# remove all files with some extension from directories and subdirectories

Tags: bash, rm

Why does command:

```
rm **/*.pyc
```

removes nothing?

What is the proper way to achieve expected behavior?

Answer (score 9):

To make your command work, you need to enable `globstar` first:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

When globstar mode is enabled, `**/*.pyc` will expand to match files ending in `.pyc` in the current directory and all subdirectories.

Alternatively you could just use `find`:

```
find -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

This will search for anything ending in `.pyc` in the current directory and all subdirectories, deleting whatever it finds. To restrict it to only match files, you can add the `-type f` switch as well, although this may not be a problem (and wouldn't have been the case in your original command).

Or, if your version of find doesn't understand `-delete`:

```
find -type f -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: this is an incredible answer - Been devving for 10+ years and never come across this! works so easily - even on Windows Git Bash - Why is this not on by default!